# Error while creating delta tables in apache spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, delta

I'm reading data from csv file and loading the data into delta table

I'm getting the following error while creating delta table

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o33.save.
: org.apache.spark.SparkClassNotFoundException: [DATA_SOURCE_NOT_FOUND] Failed to find the data source: delta. Please find packages at `https://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html`.
```

here is my code

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("DeltaExample") \
    .getOrCreate()

csv_file = "F:\\Data\Test\\file.csv"

df_data = spark.read.csv(csv_file, header=True, inferSchema=True,sep=',')
df_data.write.format("delta").save("F:\\Data\\out\\test_delta")
```

can anyone suggest how to fix this error and store data into delta table
i've installed spark successfully, my spark version is 3.5.0

Comment: You need to add `delta` libraries in your path to run python program.

Comment: can you tell me the libraries which i have to add

Comment: Go to this https://delta.io/learn/getting-started website and check pyspark shell